# Windows cannot access service on IP

Tags: windows, networking

Last week I updated my "server" Windows 10 machine to 20H2 and am I now experiencing a strange problem.

I have various web services running on multiple ports, for example 8081 and 6800.

When I access the service on port http://localhost:8081 it works, I can login an use the app. What doesn't work is http://192.168.10.2:8081, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

When I repeat the process but for port 6800, it works fine on both http://localhost:6800 and http://192.168.10.2:6800.

BUT I have this port forwarded through NAT to this machine and I cannot access it from outside the network.

For these tests all firewalls are disabled.

My ipconfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-1B-0D-DF-20-02
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a13b:4fad:1b90:e4df%3(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 102505229
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-6E-40-C8-1C-1B-0D-DF-20-02
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-1B-0D-DF-20-02
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5922:5cee:6e44:d343%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : May 25, 2021 9:24:59 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : May 26, 2021 9:51:47 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 136059661
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-6E-40-C8-1C-1B-0D-DF-20-02
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-F4-E2-54
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d094:8527:d9ae:4712%35(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.176.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 587208029
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-6E-40-C8-1C-1B-0D-DF-20-02
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

When I check who is using port 6800:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 6800).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
      0       0       60          8                 0   0 Idle
    693     103   305988     173284      18.64   9944   0 MyServiceName
```

But for 8081 I get:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8081).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   4686       0      208       2864      86.67      4   0 System
```

So to check a bit deeper with `netsh http show servicestate view=requestq` I get:

```
Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
    Version: 2.0
    State: Active
    Request queue 503 verbosity level: Basic
    Max requests: 1000
    Number of active processes attached: 1
    Process IDs:
        14432
    URL groups:
    URL group ID: F300000040000002
        State: Active
        Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
        Properties:
            Max bandwidth: inherited
            Max connections: inherited
            Timeouts:
                Timeout values inherited
            Number of registered URLs: 1
            Registered URLs:
                HTTP://*:8081/
        Server session ID: F200000020000002
            Version: 2.0
            State: Active
            Properties:
                Max bandwidth: 4294967295
                Timeouts:
                    Entity body timeout (secs): 120
                    Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
                    Request queue timeout (secs): 120
                    Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
                    Header wait timeout (secs): 120
                    Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
```

Process ID 14432 is the correct process.

When I try `http://[::1]:8081/` it works too just fine, when I try `http://[fe80::5922:5cee:6e44:d343]:8081` it also works.

Just `192.168.10.2:8081` not.

At this point I'm running out of ideas how to troubleshoot this any further but I'm thinking that Hyper-V and ipv6 are messing something up

Comment: It's not Hyper-V or IPv6. System (PID 4) is listening on that port, so your service can't listen on it. You need to address that.

Comment: Could your services be listening on the other IP address?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I double checked, now it's not my service, but it claims it's listening on http://*:8081. Before the Windows update it worked fine, so it should be still listening. The service does not report an error that 8081 is already in use.

Comment: @joeqwerty when using URL reservations they are managed by a system process which listens on the TCP port and then dispatches request to services according to the specific URLs they reserved. It's perfectly fine for the actual TCP port to be listened on by System (PID 4).

Comment: What is PID 14432? Seems like a logical place to start.

Comment: 14432 is the correct process.

Comment: So I tried using local ipv6 addresses too, and those work fine!

Comment: Can someone please provide a proper reason why this was downvoted and closed for "Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices"? I didn't include enough debug information?

Answer (score 1):

I found somewhere on a very old topic to try `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0`.

No idea why, but that worked.